# Composer command for PHP Microsoft Graph API install removing already installed PHP packages in CentOS Linux

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, composer-php, centos7

I was trying below command to install PHP Microsoft Graph API:

```
composer require microsoft/microsoft-graph
```

Everything works fine, but it removed my already installed packages like sendgrid, starbank etc.

I tried using below command and it installed but now script is not working:

```
composer require microsoft/microsoft-graph --no-update
```

PHP Code Snippet:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Error Coming while running test a.php file:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /data/app/magicbox/a.php on line 10

Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /data/app/magicbox/a.php on line 10
```

Any idea why this is happening or install Graph Microsoft API without removing already installed packages in CentOS Linux.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how this problem only occurs when using CentOS. Also, why not install Guzzle when you need it?

Comment: Finally, the code you've shared and the error message do not match - how could this error be thrown in line 10 if `new GuzzleHttp\Client` is used in line five of the code?

Comment: I was able to make it work by installing and re-installing sendgrid... my issue was with --no-update